# Difference of lists with unknown datatype

Tags: list, haskell, polymorphism

I'm trying to get the difference between two lists like this:

```
[(Char, Char, a)] -> [(Char, Char, a)] -> [(Char, Char, a)]
```

where `a` can be any datatype. The problem with doing `\\` is that `a` is not an instance of `Ord`. Is there a smart solution? I tried making complicated stuff where I first removed `a` and then tried to compare the two lists but it got so messy... I guess it can be done smartly with a `map` or something but I'm still new to Haskell so I haven't really got the hang of it.

Comment: How do you expect to do difference without at least an `Eq` constraint?  Are you saying you want to only look at the two `Char` elements and compare based on that?

Comment: You should give us an example. There is a solution if you ignore the third component when comparing triples.

Comment: Yes I want to ignore the third component, sorry for being unclear!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well in order to do this you absolutely need something of type

```
eq :: (Char, Char, a) -> (Char, Char, a) -> Bool
```

If you can't do that, then there's no sane way to find the difference. Imagine if I decide `a` to be `IO ()`, obviously there's no sane equality between `IO ()`'s so if you want to keep `a` truly polymorphic, you have to ignore it for the comparison test.

This is pretty easy to implement

```
compChars (c1, c2, _) (c1', c2', _) = c1 == c1' && c2 == c2'
```

Now we can general version of `\\` that `Data.List` provides, `deleteFirstsBy` (no clue on the naming scheme there)

```
 diff = deleteFirstsBy compChars
```